# Why is PWA not working in Iphone even that is is working on mac?

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, safari, progressive-web-apps

Hello Everyone i have been trying to do my first PWA project and for some reason only Iphone is not working tried different mobiles and different OS
the code i am going to share works on Android (Chrome and Edge), Windows PCs(Chrome and edge) , Mac  (Chrome) , but when i try it on iphone nothing happens and no errors is found.
one more thing the website i am using is a virtual directory inside my domain , and i can't host the files on the root of the domain

Index.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

<title>Pwa 1 </title>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="module" src="https://example.com/pwa/empty.js"></script>
<script>

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://example.com/pwa/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
Hello 

</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "My PWA Sample App",
    "short_name" : "PWA",
    "start_url": "https://example.com/pwa/",
     "description": "test pwa.",
    "scope" : "https://example.com/pwa/",
    "id":"index.html",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#ffee00",
    "background_color": "#ffee00",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait"
    
}
```

sw.js

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-site-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
 
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});



self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        return fetch(event.request).then(
          function(response) {
            // Check if we received a valid response
        
            if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }

            // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
            // and because we want the browser to consume the response
            // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
            // to clone it so we have two streams.
            var responseToCache = response.clone();

            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
              });

            return response;
          }
        );
      })
    );
});
```

please advice on how to get it to work on iphones on both chrome and safari, thanks

Comment: It is one of the most used OSs in USA, and here we are, looking for the same answer that nobody seems to know...

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a prompt to install the PWA, such a thing [doesn't exist on iOS](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/installation/#ios-and-ipados-installation). Why? You'd need to ask Apple.